# Statistical tool(s) to correlate perceptions with Likert-type scales

Tags: statistical-significance, likert, statistical-learning

In relation to perceptions of teachers, I want to measure:

1. **perception of helpfulness**
2. **required level of helpfulness** for the respondent to be satisfied, and
3. **how important helpfulness is** (as an aspect for a teacher to have judged by the same respondent.)

I have chosen to use a Likert-type scale for all three questions:

1. My teacher was helpful: Strongly disagree - Strongly agree
2. How helpful I want the teacher to be: I want the teacher's (helpfulness) to be Likert scaled.
3. How important is helpfulness from the teacher: (Helpfulness) from a teacher is of Likert importance to me

#### Questions

- Is there a better way to measure these three variables than using a Likert type scale?
- Which is the appropriate statistical tool(s) for assessing correlation that between all three variables?

Answer (score 2):

Likert scaled items are probably about as good as you are going to get for somewhat amorphous questions like these - it's not like you can measure these on an interval scale.

To correlate ordinally scaled variables you can use Spearman's rank correlation.